# Yii2 third-party PHP class

Tags: php, class, yii, yii2

I want to install a third-party PHP class for my application. How should I do that in Yii2? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: This needs more information and context.

Answer (score 6):

The easy way to do it is just register your class in any namespaces defined by Yii2 and use it in file as `use app\namespace\classname;`

Answer (score 4):

Like FIMAk said it is well documented in docs but still it wasn't very clear how to me how to use downloaded library with autoloader class. So here is what I done:

1) create new folder in `vendor` directory and put library there

2) require autoloader in entry script before Yii is included, in case of basic application template it is `path_to_yii_installation/web/index.php`

For example, in one of the projects on which I worked before I had requirement to generate Excel sheets, I found that PHPExcel is best library to do this. So I included PHPExcel autoloader like this:

`require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/excel/PHPExcel.php');`

My complete `index.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
// defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/excel/PHPExcel.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

3) at the top of your controller, model, or wherever you want to use library add `use LibraryClassName` and that is it.

Comment: Could you expand on step 2 by means of an example. My index.php has "require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');" so does this mean that step is done?

Comment: @crafter better now?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is good described in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html).

You can find out how to install:

1. using composer;
2. using Downloaded Libraries;

   - If a library carries its own class autoloader;
   - If a library does not provide a class autoloader, but its class naming follows PSR-4;
   - And if neither of the above is the case;

Answer (score 2):

add third party lib in composer.json and hit one command

```
 composer update
```

always go for composer based libs.